# how do I solve this recursive formula: T(1) = 1 and T(n - 1) + 3

Tags: recurrence-relations

Im not sure im doing this correctly but it seems that I am getting this

T(1) = 1

T(2) = T(2-1) + 3 = T(1) + 3 = 1 + 3

T(3) = T(3-1) + 3 = T(2) + 3 = 1 + 3 + 3

T(4) = T(4-1) + 3 = T(3) + 3 = 1 + 3 + 3 + 3

How do I solve this?

Comment: What is your $$T(n)$$?

Comment: T(n) = T(n-1) + 3

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula $$T_n=1+(n-1)\cdot3$$